# GUI vs Terminal Launch: Different look of applications

Tags: command-line, gui, appearance

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04. When I launch gparted from GUI it looks like an "old windows 95" (or something like that) application, but when I type `sudo gparted` it has this Kubuntu look.

[image: Kubuntu look:]

[image: windows 95]

I saw similar behavior on Xubuntu 16.04 with SimpleScan

Comment: btw, you should use `gparted-pkexec` from the cmd line rather than `sudo`

Comment: @chaskes why? in which way is it better?

Comment: Please, **never** run GUI applications with `sudo`. It can mess up your computer. Instead use `gksudo`.

Comment: gparted-pkexec is designed to let you safely open gparted from the cmd line. As the above comment says, sudo is not. gksudo is fine if you have it installed. There are several answers in the site about why this is bad. Also, this issue is the answer to your question as well (although I'll let someone else give you a full answer). The style info in your profile are not being found when you run it as root.

Comment: Use `gksudo` while launching GUI apps from terminal. `sudo` can do more than you think

Comment: Simeone should add an answer to be accepted. You should not post an answer as a comment.

Comment: @Helio Consider it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes are implemented on a per user basis. Installing one for your user won't result in a change to the root theme. launching with sudo results in the use of roots profile rather than your own. You can prove this to yourself rather simply. the command `sudo -i` will launch an interactive shell with sudo permissions. None of the scripts in your ~/bin directory will respond to tab completion like they would if you were under your own profile and the command `pwd` clearly shows you are in the `/root` directory as sudo rather than the `home/you` directory (where you is your username).